# jQuery $("a").live() not capturing all new links

Tags: javascript, jquery

Capturing all links.

```
$("a").live("click", function() {
    alert($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

jquery.truncate.js adds in this.

```
obj.html(str1 + "<div class='truncate-ellipsis' style='display: inline;'>" + options.ellipsisText +
                "</div><div  class='truncate-more' style='display: none;'>" + str2 + "</div>" +
                "<div class='clear'></div>" +
                "<a href='#' class='truncate-more-link'>" + options.moreText + "</a>"
        );
```

But when i click the "showmore" on a truncate object (which is a description that exceeds some designated amount of characters), the click does not get captured!  Any thoughts?

The content is added in through an ajax call to the server to get a bunch of peoples comments, the comments that run off into way to much get truncated! thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>Use `.attr('className')` - the `class` attribute is called `className` in JavaScript since `class` is a reserved (yet unused) keyword.</strike> (jQuery automatically converts `class` to `className`)

<strike>And since empty alerts won't show up that's most likely the reason why you think your handlers are not firing.</strike> Actually, that's one of the reasons why `console.log()` is much better for debugging than `alert()` even though I have to admin I often prefer `alert()` due to it simply showing up without me having to open Firebug.

Another reason for your code not working could be a `click()` handler somewhere up the DOM tree which calls `e.stopPropagation()` and thus prevents the event from bubbling to the top where the live event's handler is listening.

Comment: Well, great piece of information, but not the right answer.  the `$("a").live(...)` works on ALL other links in the page.  Even the other ones created by the server side call, except these ones....

Comment: alert does fire no matter what... http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/y9Usw/ works with `.attr('class')` -- try changing it to `.attr('hjirhig')` -- it will still fire the alert, just showing undefined. Tested in Firefox 4

Comment: @Gary: Not if the argument is `undefined`

Comment: Ok you got it, I did not realize that the jquery.truncate caused it to stop.  Drr how silly of me!  i cant believe i could not see that.  Thanks for saying the obvious.

Comment: Alerts will fire if argument is undefined

Comment: @Michael: `alert()` in firebug console will not cause a window to show up

Comment: @ThiefMaster, you're wrong about having to use `.attr('className')` instead of `.attr('class')`. Indeed it is a reserved word in javascript, but jQuery normalises that use with `.attr`. See code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js, line 2035

Comment: @ThiefMaster  Though you were correct on the propagation fact the other parts of your answers were incorrect.  Such as $jqueryEl.attr("class") does infact bring up the correct class name(s) for the element.  Empty alerts do show up, and alert(undefined) does work as well...  So with that in mind, i will not be upping your answer as correct since there are several incorrect statements.

Comment: Interesting. `alert()` doesn't show but `alert(undefined)` does.

Comment: Nice job.  I like the ferocity :)